# Creation of linked list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to implement linked list through this code... I think the first node gets created and its takes data but pointer to the next node is not working for the second time it says segmentation fault... Please help

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *root;

void append(int num)
{
    struct node *conductor;

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new node;
        root->data = num;
        root->next = NULL;
        conductor = conductor->next;
    } else {
        conductor = root;
        while (conductor != NULL)
            conductor = conductor->next;
        conductor->next = new node;
        conductor = conductor->next;
        conductor->next = NULL;
        conductor->data = num;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *conductor;
    conductor = root;

    while (conductor->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d->", conductor->data);
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    printf("%d->", conductor->data);
}

int main()
{
    int choice, num;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter the choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d", &num);
            append(num);
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: In your `append` function, when the loop end what will the value of `conductor` be? Won't it be `NULL`? Would it not be better to loop while `conductor->next` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Fix your indentation. Switch your compiler warnings ON. Fix all uninitialized variables access (I mean **fix**: think what you wrote and change it properly in algorithm, not just init tie variable blindly like `struct node *conductor = NULL;` and crash again). And use debugger.

Comment: Code of user3286661's answer a bit changed (still far from good C++ code, but check the differences): http://cpp.sh/5kfu Changes to note: constructor usage for `Node`, see how it made `append` simpler (and new `insert` too). `append` doesn't use if-else branching, but only single if branch with early exit. Temporary `Node *conductor` is always acquired with initialized value. Memory is released. `while (1)` changed to more accurate `do ... while (3 != choice);`. Next step would be to wrap whole linked list into it's own class, to remove `root` global var and release memory in destructor (OOP).

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks for the code...... I saw how 'user3286661' wrote the code ...... Can you please help me with this piece of code    Line 8.. Node(const int data_, Node * next_ = nullptr) : data(data_), next(next_) {} and why num is there in.... new Node(num)

Comment: It's constructor definition (special function called when Node is instantiated) with one parameter `data_` mandatory, and other `next_` optional (being set to `nullptr` value by default). Then `new Node(num)` will allocate memory for `Node` instance, and call the constructor with `(num, nullptr)` arguments, the constructor will set the `data`/`next` values of that instance to `num`/`nullptr` values. See some tutorial about C++ classes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *root;

void append(int num)
{
    struct node *conductor;

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new node;
        root->data = num;
        root->next = NULL;
        // conductor = conductor->next; This was not needed at all.
    } else {
        conductor = root;
        while (conductor->next != NULL) // You were doing conductor != NULL
            conductor = conductor->next;
        conductor->next = new node;
        conductor = conductor->next;
        conductor->next = NULL;
        conductor->data = num;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *conductor;
    conductor = root;
    if (conductor == NULL) return; // Returning if root is NULL
    while (conductor->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d->", conductor->data);
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    printf("%d\n", conductor->data);
}

int main()
{
    int choice, num;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter the choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d", &num);
            append(num);
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: It would be *very* helpful if you actually told us (especially the OP) what changes you made. For example by adding comments in the code.

Comment: While it's probably correct, it still screams for heavy refactoring, as it's still so ugly (but I understand there's little point to do that, unless OP shows he's really putting serious effort into it too). (but you stayed faithful to original, so I'm not saying you should change it, just to warn OP it's still just the beginning)

Comment: you also need to check in `display` for `root` is null or not

Comment: @Ped7g I need some more help to improve this code... As i need to improve this memory complexity so if you can plz help

Comment: @Mike3096: when you want to solve memory complexity and bad performance, stop using pointers and linked lists. `std::vector<int>` will do everything your `node` is doing, faster and with less memory. When you want to learn how to use new/delete and pointers, then probably get some good book. But the above code is memory wise optimal (if you require single direction linked list), so I'm not sure why you mention memory complexity.